# How can I embed JSX within a string in React native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm creating a simple app that helps learners to memorize words.
In the app, I have phrases.
In a phrase of them, of course there are words.
If a user tap a word, my app will navigate to another screen where you see something like the definition.
But first, I just want to make it touchable. And also I want to use props.
So, I thought it'd be a good idea to use JSX there.
But I tried, but that didn't work.

Here's my code:

```
import { StatusBar } from "expo-status-bar";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";

export default function App() {
  const phrases = [
    {
      id: 1,
      phrase: `You can tap this BUTTON!`,
    },
  ];

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.text}>{phrases[0].phrase}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
  text: {
    fontSize: 30,
  },
});
```

Here, I want to make the `BUTTON` to be touchable.

Here is what I tried:

```
import { StatusBar } from "expo-status-bar";
import { StyleSheet, Text, TouchableOpacity, View } from "react-native";

export default function App() {
  const phrases = [
    {
      id: 1,
      phrase: `You can tap this ${(
        <TouchableOpacity>
          <Text>BUTTON</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      )}!`,
    },
  ];

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.text}>{phrases[0].phrase}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
  text: {
    fontSize: 30,
  },
});
```

However, it just shows `[object Object]` unfortunately.
How would you do something like this?
I actually have more than 1000 objects like this, so it'd be nice if there's an efficiant way to achive this.

I'd appreciate it if you would give me some hint.

Thank you in advanse.